# Does shutting down Ubuntu really require root permissions?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I using Lubuntu 12.10. I recently noticed that when I use the shutdown option from the applications menu, it does not ask for a password or root permissions. But if I use the 'shutdown -h now' without 'sudo', computer asks for root permissions.

I humbly request Linux experts to clear my doubt.

Answer (score 2):

In [another question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/49553/how-to-give-shutdown-privileges-to-a-user) the command that the shutdown button actually calls is given:

```
dbus-send --system --print-reply --dest=org.freedesktop.ConsoleKit /org/freedesktop/ConsoleKit/Manager org.freedesktop.ConsoleKit.Manager.Stop
```

It sends a signal to a daemon that is allowed to shutdown the system. There is no need to be root for sending this signal.
You are however not allowed to execute `shutdown` directly without root privileges.

Comment: Thank you Tim. Does that mean anyone can send the signal and shutdown the system?

Comment: In principle yes, but yuo can configure it. The standard is, that you can only shutdown the system, if you are the only user logged in. http://askubuntu.com/questions/1190/how-can-i-make-shutdown-not-require-admin-password explains how to change it.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you either need root or access to the physical system. This is because linux/unix were designed primarily as concurrent multi-user systems (mainframes, servers), unlike your standard single-user PC. If you were connected to a system hosting 29 users on different ssh connections, letting one of them shut down the server would be potentially disastrous for the other users.